# Menu in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does Bootstrap provide a functionality or similiar based on the picture that I have uploaded.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Yes. Customize the dropdown menu: http://bootply.com/fcQDmJEZDd

Answer (score 0):

Yes in twitter bootstrap you can do something like this and attach it to a static button and subsequently place it on the navbar like the one in your example :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html) for more components

There is also a live examples of a similar element on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinaybvk/0rzwazh7/) and another [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bseth99/dJDHd/) which both work when i tested them using twitter bootstrap.

```js
 $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

      var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

      $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
         .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
            .end()
         .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

      return false;

   });
```

```css
.btn-input {
   display: block;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control {
    text-align: left;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control span:first-child {
   left: 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   right: 25px;
}

.btn-input .btn.form-control .caret {
   margin-top: -1px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<br/><br/>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h5>Normal Dropdown Button</h5>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

      </div>

   </div>
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h5>Dropdown Button w/.form-control</h5>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="btn-group">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

      </div>

   </div>
   <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h5>Dropdown Button w/custom styles</h5>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
                   <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>

      </div>

   </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

### Hope this helps :)

Update

You can see some samples of dropdowns on jfiddle too [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/) :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">

 <div id="navbar-example" class="navbar navbar-static">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container" style="width: auto;">

        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project Name</a>
        
        <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav" role="navigation">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a id="drop1" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#Action">Action</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#anotherAction">Another action</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" id="drop2" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo!</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://bing.com" target="_blank">Bing</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- /navbar-example -->
  
                
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
```

This example uses bootstrap 2.3.2 instead of 3.

Comment: is it available for bootstrap version 2?

Comment: I added an update section for you with another jfiddle example, hope it helps and lemme know if there are any other problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap already has that feature build-in. You do not even have to write a single line of JavaScript by yourself.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfdej2ee/

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <p><strong>Action 1</strong></p> Some Text</a>
            </li>
            <hr/>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <p><strong>Action 2</strong></p> Some Text</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <p><strong>Action 3</strong></p> Some Text</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
  Sample Content

</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: is it available for bootstrap version 2?

Comment: Are you still using Bootstrap 2? I hope you are not joking. Boostrap 3 has been out for 3 years or more, and Bootstrap 4 is right around the corner.